# storing functions in a std::vector works ok on linux but doesn't even compile on windows

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading

This program that stores functions in a `std::vector` works with g++ 7.2.0 on linux but doesn't compile on windows with visual c++ 2017 v15.5.4
the error is for `sin()`, `cos()`, `tan()` in the vector:

```
E0289 cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "sin" is intended.
```

I don't see how to modify it so that it also works on windows.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::function<double(double)> AFunc;

std::vector<AFunc> funcs = {
  sin,
  cos,
  tan,
  [](double x) { return x*x; },
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << funcs[0](2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << funcs[1](2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << funcs[2](2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << funcs[3](2) << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: The funny thing is that this error message is only produced by IntelliSense and *not* by the compiler. It's rare that IntelliSense produces a clearer error message.

Comment: Note that the program uses ::sin() and not std::sin().  That this compiles is not exactly a feature, the msvc++ headers are hard-ass about it.

Comment: @ChristianHackl hmm..  IS errors not necessary are errors, but hints of possible error , it's result of that mechanism that allows you to cross-reference ids in code is unable to find a proper candidate in scanned code (to show it by "go to identifier" kind of commands). It's not a compilation error.

Comment: @Hans Passant their headers still import std::sin from global scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sin`, `cos` and `tan` are provided in multiple overloads (for the various floating point types), so just citing their name isn't enough to resolve exactly which function you mean. You can either resolve the ambiguity with the cast in @max66 answer, or just use a lambda, which is IMO clearer syntax and less typing:

```
std::vector<AFunc> funcs = {
  [](double x) { return sin(x); },
  [](double x) { return cos(x); },
  [](double x) { return tan(x); },
  [](double x) { return x*x; },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> I don't see how to modify it so that it also works on windows.

What about casting to the requested type?

```
std::vector<AFunc> funcs = {
  static_cast<double(*)(double)>(&sin),
  static_cast<double(*)(double)>(&cos),
  static_cast<double(*)(double)>(&tan),
  [](double x) { return x*x; },
};
```

Comment: @水飲み鳥 - why not? So you can have catch errors in compiling phase. Thanks.